# Is there an age limit on applications for Maitre de Conferences?

Tags: career-path, job, france, age

I'm interested in pursuing a permanent, independent research position in neuroscience in France. However, I'm getting conflicting information from different researchers in the country about whether or not there is an age limit. One institute has told me that it's not possible to put forth an application for a position like this after the age of 35 (I'm 42). Another has told me that no such rule exists and what matters is how much you have produced since your PhD diploma (in my case, 6 years). I've done as much googling as I can and I can't find any official documentation about an age limit.

If it matters, I already have my qualification through Galaxie and I speak French at a B2 level and eager to improve.

Thanks.

Comment: Admitting that I don't know much on the topic, it seems like Maitre de Conferences is both teaching and research.  The research-only version would be Chargé de recherche.  Am I confused?  If not, which one are you looking for?

Comment: I believe Chargé de recherche is technically under the umbrella of MCF -- but either way, I'd be interested to know if there are age limits for either/both.

Comment: Besides legal terms, what you pursue certainly requires you being in touch with an university, a group, a director. They know better than us, both for the above legal terms as well as for all possible issues/chances etc.

Comment: @KatB I think chargé de recherches is a position at the CNRS where you are not forced to give class. Maitre de conférence is the lowest grade (the one when you are recruited) when you are forced to give class at the university for roughly half of your employment time.

Answer (score 5):

There were an official biological age limit for positions in France but it has been removed now.

Now it can still be there in an un-official manner of course. But at least it is no longer in the texts.

Source: a formation I followed at my ecole doctorale (advices to pursue academic carreer).